VS Code sync not being applied
I used npkill to clean up some node_modules, but I accidentally deleted some files that caused my VS Code extensions to stop working. I uninstalled VS Code and tried to apply a sync to restore all my keybindings and extensions. Unfortunately, the sync isn't being applied, even though the changes and data are present.
I tried several commands, including turning sync off and then back on, using the Sync Now command, and checking Download Sync Activity. According to ChatGPT, Download Sync Activity shouldn't be related to file management, yet it's behaving as if it is in my case.

